# What's the difference between Bazel's py_library and py_binary rules

Tags: python, bazel, bazel-rules

Bazel's [documentation](https://bazel.build/reference/be/python#py_library) explains how to use each, but I don't understand the difference in their nature. Aren't all python files executables anyway? What difference does it make to specify it is a binary?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Executable or not?

> Aren't all python files executables anyway?

If we don't take [file permissions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chmod) into account, the answer to that question, if we are observing the behavior, is **not necessarily**. In the real world, it depends on what is written in the `python` file.

**What do I mean by "observing the behavior"?**

`Python` files can be executable in the sense that they perform "actual work" like calling methods, performing calculations, file handling, logging, etc.

Have in mind that `python` files may also have a different purpose like simply defining the `functions`, `enums`, or `classes` that are to be used from separate `python` files.

To understand the upper sentences, my recommendation is to read more about [`__main__`](https://realpython.com/if-name-main-python/) in `python`.

---

## Providing a functionality

Now imagine a use case in which it is needed to provide a set of `functions`, `enums`, or `classes` for someone else to use, but not to use them in the file in which they are written. Most of the time when there is a such requirement, it is needed to develop a library that provides all the necessary functionality.

---

## py_library

To create an artifact that is **"passive"** and is to be used by other executables you can use [`py_library`](https://bazel.build/reference/be/python#py_library) `Bazel` `python` rule. `py_library` **should not be an executable**, it creates an artifact that can be used by other artifacts such as [py_test](https://bazel.build/reference/be/python#py_test) or [py_binary](https://bazel.build/reference/be/python#py_binary).

Creating a `py_library` allows you to use that library in multiple `Bazel` targets and provides a clear message to the developers that the current target has a dependency on the specified `py_library`.

---

## py_binary

Is **the executable** that is intended to be run and to perform a certain set of tasks.

---

## TL;DR

> What difference does it make to specify it is a binary?

1. Use `py_binary` when you need to **actually execute the code** written in the `python` source files
2. Use `py_binary` if it is needed to **execute defined functionality** from a separate file (e.g. perform setup/cleanup) like it is described in the second example of [py_binary](https://bazel.build/reference/be/python#py_binary_examples)
3. Use `py_library` when you need to provide **passive** functionalities that will be utilized from a separate `python` (or even a different programming language) file/artifact
4. My recommendation is that you also watch [this Youtube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8P3m1-U7v0k&ab_channel=KrisFoster) that gives good insight on when/how to use, and how to "connect" `py_binary`, `py_library` and `py_test`

Answer (score 1):

A `py_library` is a group of Python source files that can be utilized by other Bazel targets as dependencies. It itself is not an executable file. On the other hand, a `py_binary` is an independently executable Python application. It can be directly executed after being built from one or more py library targets.

The distinction between a static library and an executable file in other programming languages is analogous to that between a py library and py binary. An executable is a standalone program that can be run directly, but a static library is a group of object files that may be linked into other executables.

All .py files are regarded as executables in Python since the Python interpreter can use them directly. Not all Python programs, meanwhile, are created to be executed immediately. Other Python applications can import and utilize certain Python files as libraries. These Python files are defined in Bazel by the py library rule, whereas directly executable Python applications are defined by the `py_binary` rule.

Comment: So `py_library` can both be linked to other executables or be executed itself while for `py_binary` only the latter is possible?